# Adding tabItems-.Header to a List<T>

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have multiple `TabItems` in my `TabControl`; `tabItem1`, `tabItem2`, `tabItem3`...these are `CloseableTabItem`. if all tabitems are aktive, how can i add the `tabItem.Header` to a `List<string>`?

Comment: What have you tried/what problems are you facing? Just call `Add` ... also, `CloseableTabItem` doesn't seem to be in C#'s BCL, what kind of a class is it and where does it come from?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You're question is a little vague. To improve it, please include the important portions of your code illustrating the problem you're experiencing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        List<string> listItems = new List<string>();

        foreach (TabItem item in tabControl1.Items)
        {
            if (item.IsEnabled)
                listItems.Add(item.Header.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention any list boxes.

Comment: the original question didn't, it has since been edited, so I have since edited my answer

Comment: sorry i forget to add <string>